# Homomorphism induced by antipode preserving map carries generator to odd power of itself

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying a question in $\textit{Munkres}$, Section $57$:

Let $h: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be continuous and antipode-preserving with $h(b_0)=b_0$ where $b_0 = (1,0)$. Show that $h_*$ carries the generator of $\Pi_1(S^1,b_0)$ to an odd power of itself.

Then as in proof of Theorem $57.1$:

Let $q:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be the map $q(z)=z^2$. Then $q$ is a quotient map and covering map. Also, $q(h(-z)) = q(h(z)).$

As $q$ is a quotient map, the map $q \circ h$ induces a continuous map $k : S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ such that $k\circ q = q \circ h$. Then $q(b_0)=k(b_0)=b_0$ and $h(-b_0)=-b_0$.

There is a hint in the book which says:

If $k$ is the map constructed above, show $k_*$ does the same.

So I assume that $$k_*[f]=(2n+1)\cdot[f]$$ where $[f]$ is the generator of $\Pi_1(S^1,b_0)$.

Now,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{split}
(k \circ q)_*[f] & = k_*[q \circ f] \\
& = k_*([f]*[f]) \\ & = k_*([f]) * k_*([f]) \\
& = ((2n+1)\cdot[f]) * ((2n+1)\cdot[f])
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray*}

where I have used that $q_*[f]=2\cdot[f]$ by definition of $q$.

Also,
$$
(q \circ h)_*[f] = q_*(h_* [f]) = h_*[f] * h_*[f]
$$

Using $k \circ q = q \circ h$, we obtain $h_*[f]=(2n+1)\cdot[f]$.

However, I'm having trouble proving the result for $k_*$. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: There is something wrong in the statement "with $h(b_0)=h(b_0)$", I think it's not what you wanted to say.

Comment: @R.Alexandre, sorry I made the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\overline{f}$ be the lift of $f$.

Consider $k_*[f]=[k\circ f]=[k\circ q \circ \overline{f}]=[q\circ h\circ \overline{f}]$. Now $h \circ \overline{f}$ is a path from $-b_0$ to $b_0$. Therefore, $$[h \circ \overline{f}]=(n\cdot[f])*[\overline{f}]$$ for some $n \geq0$. Further, $[q \circ f]=2[f]$. Hence, 
$$k_*[f]=[q\circ(h \circ \overline{f})]=(2n+1)\cdot[f]$$