# A consequence of quotient map from unit circle to itself

Tags: general-topology, circles, homotopy-theory, quotient-set

In Part II of General Topology, Munkres, Theorem 57.1 states that if $h:S^1\to S^1$ is continuous and antipode-preserving, then $h$ is not nulhomotopic.

There are some definitions I should clarify here: $S^1$ is the unit circle on the $xy$-plane, so we could parametrize $S^1$ as $(\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$, $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$. A map $f:S^1\to S^1$ is antipode-preserving if for $x\in S^1$ we have $f(-x)=-f(x)$, which means for every pair of antipodes $\{x, -x\}$, their images under $f$ are also antipodes $\{f(x), f(-x)\}=\{f(x),-f(x)\}$. Finally, $h$ is nulhomotopic means $h$ is path-homotopic to a constant map $e: S^1\to S^1$, by definition this means there is a continuous map $H:S^1\times [0,1]\to S^1$ such that $H(x, 0)=h(x), H(x, 1)=e(x)$. There are other details about this proof, but these should be enough for the question I would like to ask.

In the proof, by composition with some rotation map, we can further assume $h(b_0)=b_0$, where $b_0=(1,0)$. We define a map $q:S^1\to S^1$ by $q(x)=x^2$ (in the complex sense), hence
$$q(\cos \theta,\sin\theta)=(\cos2\theta, \sin2\theta).$$

It is easy to see $q$ is a quotient map, because it is a continuous closed surjective map. Note that $q$ maps each pair of antipode points to the same point, and the inverse of any point in $S^1$ under $q$ is a pair of antipode.

**My question: The steps thereafter states that since $q$ is a quotient map, so $q\circ h$ induces a continuous map $k:S^1\to S^1$ such that $k\circ q=q\circ h$.** I didn't quite get this point because I don't remember such result from the chapter of quotient map. My idea to get myself through this property is to let $k=q\circ h\circ q^{-1}$ and show that $k$ is well-defined. Indeed, for $x\in S^1$, $q^{-1}(x)$ is not a single point, but a pair of antipodes, then $h(q^{-1}(x))$ is also a pair of antipodes, then $q$ maps $h(q^{-1}(x))$ into a single point, thus $k$ is well-defined. I believe $k$ is continuous so I'm not troubling myself to show it, but is there a general way to see why $q$ being a quotient map will generate the continuous map $k$?

I have noted this question has been asked twice before, but the specific question is different from mine in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236704/homomorphism-induced-by-antipode-preserving-map-carries-generator-to-odd-power-o) and the answer to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2259690/a-continuous-map-induced-by-a-continuous-map-munkres) doesn't answer my question in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply Munkres' Theorem 22.2. Consider the map $g = p \circ h : S^1 \to S^1$. Each set $p^{-1}(z)$ consists of two antipodal points $w_1, w_2 = -w_1$ (these are the two complex square roots of $z$). But obviously $g$ is constant on all $p^{-1}(z)$ since $g(w_2) = h(w_2)^2 = h(-w_1)^2 = (-h(w_1))^2 = h(w_1)^2 = g(w_1)$.

Comment: This implication is very subtle (for me). Thanks for pointing that out!